# Pascal ABC.Net Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
const inputfile='corpuscle.in';
      outputfile='corpuscle.out';
var s1,s2,s3,s4,s5:string;
    n,m,q,w,e:integer;
begin
  assign(input,inputfile);
  assign(output,outputfile);
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);
  readln(input,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5);
  write(output,s2[1]);
  close(output);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

В коде одно место с обращением по индексу `write(output,s2[1]);`

Значит, строка `s2` просто **не прочитана** из файла.

Покажите содержимое файла `'corpuscle.in'`

Кстати, input и output в старом Паскале были связаны с клавиатурой и консольным выводом. В ABC их можно переназначать (раньше можно было, но это плохой тон)?